# Accessing widget factory options from external method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, widget

I want to populate a select list with all of the option names in a widget factory, and on select, display the option value, but I can't get the syntax and I keep getting  "uncaught error: cannot call methods on [widget name] prior to initialization...

Can anybody show me the code to get a list of all the current options from outside the widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to formulate the answer correctly as I am trying to use it since a few days, nevertheless, I could read the following article recently and you'll have the answer inside:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/an-in-depth-review-of-jquerys-widget-factory/

Comment: Yes, this is an excellent article. I have built a whole book of articles now and am slowly (evenings and weekends) plowing my way through this. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing this:

```
$('.some-element').yourWidget('option');
```

Before you've actually instantiated the widget like this:

```
$('.some-element').yourWidget();
```